# Image position changes copying image data from one canvas to another

Tags: paperjs

I'm using paper.js to place an image on a paper.js canvas. I then copy that canvas's dataURL to create a new canvas. When I do so unless I hard code the position of the raster, it ends up in the wrong position, but drawn paths are in the correct position. Working codpene [here](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/abmqKgK)
[image: incorrect]
[image: correct]

If I use paper's raster object syntax:

```
var image = new paper.Raster({
position: paper.view.center
})
```

It has no effect.
If I use paper's raster object syntax with a hard coded position it corrects the positionioning:

```
var image = new paper.Raster({
position: new paper.Point(400,600)
})
```

The image is corrected. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess this happens because `paper.view.center` is not `(400,600)` when you create the raster. You can see that by logging it: `console.log(paper.view.center)` just before creating your raster. You might need to wait for [the document to be loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) before creating your raster?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @arthur.sw